# Where to Update a JFrame

Tags: jframe

Hi I have a JFrame class that I update based on information I recieve from another class. I have created an update method within the JFrame which I use to update the different objects on the page. But my Question is is that the correct thing to do?

Comment: Can you show us your update method?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it however you want, there is no "right" way. It's all a matter of preference. Personally, I like that way of doing it. In almost all of my GUI's I have a method called "update()" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

its depends on how updates are being triggered, but using event-listeners and actionCommands might be helpful. I don't necessarily like this methods but it is convenient.